# How to update (not overwrite) a multiple choice lookup field using updatelistitems

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a list in sharepoint foundation. Each item has a field which is of type lookup. A user can select multiple values in this field.

Some items already have values selected in this field. I would like to update a number of items using the updatelistitems call in the Lists web service. Whenever I update an item though, the new value overwrites the existing value in this field instead of appending to it.

Is there a way to append the new value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first retrieve the selected values of these fields and hold in a collection and then merge with your new values and update back to the field...

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was a better way - ie one that didn't involve a getlistitems then an updatelistitems.